# Escaping a question mark character in a column name in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, hql

I have an entity with a property whose column name contains a question mark.  How do I map the column name so that an HQL query will correctly generate SQL with the column name wrapped appropriately (i.e. [] for SQL Server) instead of substituting a parameter for the question mark?  I have tried wrapping the column name in backticks or square brackets but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backticks work fine for me. Remember to use them only in the mapping file, not in the HQL:

```
<property name="Data1" column="`Data1?`" />
```

This query:

```
session.CreateQuery("select Data1 from Foo").List();
```

Results in this SQL:

```
select foo0_.[Data1?] as col_0_0_
from Foo foo0_
```

---

Update: this is a bug in NHibernate 3.1. [Jira issue created](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2681)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. I've got this mapping:

`<subclass name="Visit">
<property name="IsFixed" column="\`Fixed?\`" />
</subclass>`

When I run this query:

`return _session.CreateQuery("select visit from Visit visit").List<Visit>();`

I get this SQL:

`select visit0_.[Fixed@p0] as Fixed14_22_
from dbo.tblVisits visit0_`

Which results in SqlException Invalid column name 'Fixed@p0'.

Comment: @MartinIngham: what NH version are you using? Dialect and Driver?

Comment: NH version = 3.1.0.4000, dialect = NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2005Dialect, driver = NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver
DB server = MS SQL Server 2008 R2, provider = System.Data.SqlClient

Comment: @MartinIngham: you've found a bug. I've opened an issue in the NH tracker (see edit)