# SQL square brackets in column name using NHibernate

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate

I have a column in a DB called":

someting[0].else.thing

because there are '.' characters in the column name I have to surround it with brackets in the hbm.xml file like so:

[someting[0].else.thing]

The problem is that this query is not allowed.

The following error is produced.

```
Message = "ERROR [42000] [DataDirect][OpenAccess ODBC]Syntax error in SQL statement.    syntax error line 1 at or after token <thing>."
```

My question is how to get around the brackets inside the column name?

I have tried: 
[someting[0].else.thing]

[someting[0].else.thing]]

["someting[0].else.thing"]

"[someting[0].else.thing]"

'[someting[0].else.thing]'

**Edit**

[something[0]].else.thing]

'something[0].else.thing'

Comment: One combination you don't seem to have tried: `[someting[0]].else.thing]`

Comment: That's a pretty bad column name.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thanks, but didn work either.

Comment: @Josh I used a different name to post on this thread, the form is the same though.

Comment: have you tried "someting[0].else.thing", ( or `&quot;someting[0].else.thing&quot;` in the xml) ?

Comment: @jbl Thats it!! Thank you, please post it as an aswer so I can mark it as such.

Comment: or have you see this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805617/escaping-a-question-mark-character-in-a-column-name-in-nhibernate basically backtick the mapping NOT the HQL!

Comment: done! Also, I would be curious of the target Database and driver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try `"someting[0].else.thing"`, ( or `&quot;someting[0].else.thing&quot;` in the xml)

See for example [SQLite: escaping table and column names correctly](http://blog.christosoft.de/2012/10/sqlite-escaping-table-acolumn-names/)

> SQlite supports ` for compatibility with MySQL and [] for
>   compatibility with MS Access and SQL Server. **But it also supports
>   double quotes, which is standard SQL**

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap column names with backticks

```
`something[0].else.thing`
```

(Not sure it works, but I don't know a way to put backticks to a comment without making it highlight things)

Comment: I hoped this would work but unfortunatelly not. The error message did change from the one above to : ERROR [42000] [DataDirect][OpenAccess ODBC]Syntax error in SQL statement. syntax error line 1 at or after token <something[0].else.thing>. This indicates that it did read more of the actual column name this time...